# Elasticsearch Metric Aggregation on Multiple Filters

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Is there a way to run a metric aggregation (value count for example) on multiple filters.  For example, I'm currently able to get the counts of successes and errors all users are getting with the following aggregation:

```
aggs = {
    "f": {
        "filters": {
            "filters": {
                "start_count": {"term": {"type": "Success"}},
                "error_count": {"term": {"type": "Error"}}
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "counts": {"value_count": {"field": "type"}}
        }
    }
}
```

Now, lets say I wanted to get the count of success and errors for specific users Mary, Joe, and Tina. How would I use aggregations and filters to achieve this?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You would do it like this by adding a filter on the three users you want and then a `terms` aggregation on the `user` field. The success/error filter aggregations will then be sub-aggregations of the users one:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "user": [
              "Mary",
              "Joe",
              "Tina"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "f": {
          "filters": {
            "filters": {
              "start_count": {
                "term": {
                  "type": "Success"
                }
              },
              "error_count": {
                "term": {
                  "type": "Error"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "counts": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "type"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```